# Telerik Openaccess ORM Update Object and Automapper

Tags: c#, orm, automapper, telerik-open-access, openaccess

I am trying to update an object using telerik openaccess orm and automapper, it works for adding the object to scope but not update.

I saw on their site someone having same issue, but the [answer](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/orm/general-discussions/using-automapper-when-updating-an-object-and-all-of-its-children.aspx) didn't really help me. here is my code which doesn't update my object :

```
try
            {
                if (!scope.Transaction.IsActive)
                    scope.Transaction.Begin();

                ObjQ objq = get_Q(scope, Id);
                bool isNew = false;

                if (objq == null)
                {
                    objq = new ObjQ();
                    isNew = true;
                }

                AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<ObjQ , ObjQ >();

                objq = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ObjQ , ObjQ>(srcQ);

                if (isNew)
                {
                    scope.Add(objq);
                }

                scope.Transaction.Commit();

                success = true;
            }
```

after this line I can see my properties reflecting the new changes but it is not the same in database

```
objq = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ObjQ , ObjQ>(srcQ);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone else who wants to do the same thing, managed to do it this way:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ObjQ , ObjQ >(srcQ, objq);
```

Comment: Well, I have to say that in my case, I came to find that Telerik Data Access doesn't like AutoMapper (or ValuInjecter for that matter). This code does not work:

    OBJ.Manutencao dbManutencao = this.mManutencaoRepository.Get(manutencao.ManutencaoID);
            {
                Mapper.Reset();
                Mapper.CreateMap<Manutencao, Manutencao>();
                Mapper.Map<Manutencao, Manutencao>(manutencao, dbManutencao);
 
                this.mUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
 
                return true;
Some properties do not get correctly mapped.